# Is it possible to extract a resource Quantity as a number that can be compared with other numbers in a Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a Helm chart where I allow users to inject their resource requests and limits for a container.

In `Values.yaml` this might look like:

```yaml
minMemory: "512Mi"
```

In my chart I would like to ensure that the users don't ask for more memory than my nodes have, i.e. "16Gi".

Is there a way to get something like this to work:

```yaml
{{- $minMemory := min "16Gi" (default "256Mi" .Values.minMemory) }}
```

The code above doesn't work as intended, because the `min` function treats the quantity string as the number `0`.

Is there a function or an example of extracting the number value of a Quantity, so that "1Ki" becomes `1024000`?